# What is the correct way to write in a bullet list: Ensure emergency Services have been contacted

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, passive-voice

Ensure emergency Services HAVE BEEN contacted.

or

Ensure emergency Services has been contacted.

Comment: This is unclear--you are not showing any bullet lists. Is the question about bullet lists, or use of has vs have?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with bullet lists. It's exactly the same whereever it's written.

Broadly, if you mean 'the emergency services' generically, then 'Ensure emergency services have been contacted' or greatly preferably 'Ensure the emergency services have been contacted'

If you mean specifically some internal department named Emergency Services then 'Ensure Emergency Services has been contacted.'